# Solve fractional inequalities that have quadratics

Tags: inequality, quadratics

Say you have $\frac{2x^2+3x-2}{2x^2-3x-2}>0$

How do you find the range of solutions? Can you just bring the denominator onto the right hand side or does that lose solutions? Never been taught how to approach these kind of inequalities.

BTW: This is not for homework or anything of a similar kind. It's just a problem that I came across in my free time.

Comment: Factorise $2x^{2}+3x-2$ and $2x^{2}-3x-2$ and all the other points which make it negative and greater than $0$ are required solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot bring the denominator to the right. That's equivalent to multiply the fraction by $2x^2-3x-2$, but then the inequality should change when this number is smaller then $0$.

What you can do is to determine those $x\in\Bbb R$ in which $2x^2+3x-2$ and $2x^2-3x-2$ have the same sign. After all $\frac ab>0$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ aro both positive or both negative.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help...it is much appreciated. Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this kind of question is to multiply both sides by the denominator **squared** which, being non-negative, preserves the inequality.

So you could go straight to

$$(2x^2+3x-2)(2x^2-3x-2)>0$$
$$\implies(2x-1)(x+2)(2x+1)(x-2)>0$$

You then just have to sketch a quick quartic graph showing the four roots and read off the solution sets.

Comment: Ah ok, that works as well. Thanks for showing me this method.